# How to make ionide-fsharp formater work in VSCode

Tags: f#, ionide

I have a problem with ionide-fsharp formatter. When I install the extension in VSCode I am not able to automaticaly format a file on save. I have fantomas installed globaly and I tried to go through FSAC, but nothing has helped. I think that I need to put something in VSCode's settings.json like I have a prettier config for typescript.

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how my own config looks like

```json
"[fsharp]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Ionide.Ionide-fsharp"
},
```

Comment: Yep, now it seems to be working! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that `editor.formatOnSave` is set to `true` (either for just the `fsharp` language or globally) and then FSAC should pick up your globally-installed Fantomas.

Comment: Hello, I already have this formatOnSave:true. This format on save works just fine for me on JS / TS files, but F# doesnt

Comment: Based on your comment I would guess that you had another f# extension installed alongside Ionide? Is that a good guess? If so, VSCode probably just couldn't pick which one to use

Comment: I only had prettier, which is formater for JavaScript, but I would also think that these 2 things didnt go well together. Therefore it wasnt working.